# how to install genymotion on vmware

Tags: android, virtualbox, vmware, genymotion

Guys I've installed genymotion on virtual box provided with setup . now every time i want to start the virtual device I've to restart my laptop & sometimes even that doesn't help . So I've decided to install that on VMWare 11 . Can anyone help me please on this issue.

If anyone can solve this error which says can't connect to virtualbox ,That would be helpful also. But I still prefer solution with VMWare .

I've tried solution like DHCP server address solution which is suggested by official support site of genymotion , but that doesn't help also.

I've tried glew solution also but their support center doesn't accept log file(text) or image of error.

Snapshot of error :

[image]

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the genymotion device in VMWare and Virtualbox? BTW you using ubuntu or windows?

Comment: Check this links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641423/not-able-to-start-genymotion-device , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662867/genymotion-does-not-start-android-virtual-device

Comment: You upload your screenshot in [imgur](http://www.imgur.com) & post the link. I'll embed it.

Comment: This may solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922077/genymotion-unable-to-start-the-genymotion-virtual-device

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, Genymotion can't be launched on a virtual machine!
This is quoted from their [faq](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support?chapter=virtual-machine-start-impossible#faq):

> Why doesn't Genymotion start from a virtual machine? Genymotion cannot
>   be run from a virtual machine. Indeed, Genymotion needs a direct
>   access to the hardware in order to provide OpenGL acceleration.
>   Running Genymotion from a virtual machine prevents it to directly
>   access the hardware components. Therefore, Genymotion is incompatible
>   when installed from VMWare, Parallels, Hyper-V or VirtualPC.

Comment: Good luck! The whole setting up thing can be a pain but once it's set it worth the effort.

Answer (score 4):

About the problem with virtual box try the following steps:
 1. Open Virtual box. Go to preferences.
 2. Click on networks option.
 3. Click on Host-only networks tab
 4. Delete all host adapters.
 5. Start Genymotion. It will automatically create a new network adapter with required settings.
The above worked for me.