# Genymotion: "The specified virtual device was not found in VirtualBox list"

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

One day I tried to launch a Genymotion virtual device and got:

[image]

Everything used to work fine. I haven't done any update. I use Genymotion 2.3.1 and Oracle VirtualBox 4.3.12 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. What could have caused the issue to arise, and how to fix it?

My configuration:

[image]

[image]

When I tried to launch the VM from VirtualBox, I get:

[image]

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Samsung Galaxy S5 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920.

The VM session was closed before any attempt to power it on.

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: SessionMachine
Interface: ISession {12f4dcdb-12b2-4ec1-b7cd-ddd9f6c5bf4d}
```

Comment: take a look at[this solution]
Your VM is in a saved state

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662867/genymotion-does-not-start-android-virtual-device

Comment: @DanialChan Thanks, good catch, right-clicking on the virtual machine on the left in VirtualBox and select "Discard saved state" solved the issue. Could you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Frank,

Your VM is in a saved stated. You will need to turn it to a powered off state or discard the saved state via the Virtual Box App.

For more info, refer to this [geny motion does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662867/genymotion-does-not-start-android-virtual-device)