# Genymotion error "specified virtual device was not found in VirtualBox list"

Tags: android, genymotion

I have downloaded a new device in **Genymotion Emulator**, and then started it. Then pop-up window appeared, saying "*specified virtual device was not found in VirtualBox list*". Then I checked my **VirtualBox**, and it really did not have the said device in the list, doesn't like the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228900/genymotion-the-specified-virtual-device-was-not-found-in-virtualbox-list) where VirtualBox still has the said device. Does anyone have any idea what just happened? Why didn't VirtualBox make the device?

I used Win 8 x64. I have another device on Genymotion that can run smoothly.

Comment: Try to start the device from the VirtualBox itself

Comment: @TiyebBellal The device doesn't even exist in VirtualBox

Comment: Download it again, you may have lost connection during the process.., usually when downloaded it appears both in Geny and VertulaBox.

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill all processes Virtual box running and then  restart again.Virtual machine's state can cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Virtual box then use Genymotion